# IPtables block port 8080 but not for localhost

Tags: mod-proxy, hudson

Currently I have an application that is running on 8080 front-ended by mod_proxy.

```
    <Location /hudson>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/hudson
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/hudson
    </Location>
```

I need to block TCP 8080 but not for the localhost how can this be done with IPtables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
// accept all tcp on port 8080 from localhost  
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT  

[...] all your other rules  
// drop all other packets  
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

If you wanted to allow also 1 (or more) external/other IP you can use this:

```
// accept tcp on port 8080 from allowed_ip  
iptables -I INPUT 3 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -s allowed_ip -j ACCEPT
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 15):

This would work:

```
iptables -A INPUT ! -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: in server listening 8080, bind only to localhost:
For apache it looks like following:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: good answer. however he might want to have over virtual hosts listen on netIP.

Comment: Yep, this would not work for all cases, but when you only need to connect from loalhost and nothing else, it's better to listen on 127.0.0.1 and don't have any iptables rules at all (especially for high loaded machines).